# Deleting rows from UITableview throws assertion error

Tags: uitableview

I've read a bunch of SO post on this but nothing I do seems to work. I am simply trying to remove all the rows in a UITableView using the delegate method:

deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Here is the code I am using:

```
- (void) clearNonATITable {

    NSMutableArray* arrIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

    if (self.arrNonATIResults.count > 0) {

        [self.accountTable beginUpdates];
        for(int i=0; i<self.arrNonATIResults.count; i++) {
            NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0];
            [self.accountTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        [self.accountTable endUpdates];


        [self.accountTable reloadData];
        [self.arrNonATIResults removeAllObjects];

    }

}
```

Here is the code I am using to populate the datasource:

```
- (void) updateNonATITable {

    [self.arrNonATIResults removeAllObjects];

    //setting up some test data - DELETE WHEN SERVICES ARE UP
    NSDictionary* dictRow1 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"Is Target",
                              @"Local Pharmaceutical", @"Company Name",
                              @"71234567", @"Company ID",
                              @"123 Anystreet", @"Address",
                              @"Small Town", @"City",
                              @"Small Cell", @"Cell 5",
                              @"Booyeah!", @"Comments",
                              nil];

    NSDictionary* dictRow2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], @"Is Target",
                              @"Big Pharmaceutical", @"Company Name",
                              @"78903456", @"Company ID",
                              @"123 Main Street", @"Address",
                              @"Big City", @"City",
                              @"Small Cell", @"Cell 5",
                              @"Brady Rules!", @"Comments",
                              nil];

    self.arrNonATIResults = (NSMutableArray*)[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dictRow1, dictRow2, nil];




    //reload table
    [self.accountTable reloadData];
    [self.accountTable scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.accountTable.frame.size.width, 38.0f) animated:YES];

}
```

The assertion error is:

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.93/UITableView.m:1582
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you remove the data in the array after removing the table rows and reloading the table.

The reliable way is to remove the data in the array first and then remove the table rows both within a `beginUpdates/endUpdates` block

```
- (void) clearNonATITable {

  NSInteger count = (NSInteger)self.arrNonATIResults.count;
  if (count > 0) {

    NSMutableArray *arrIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self.accountTable beginUpdates];
    [self.arrNonATIResults removeAllObjects];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      [arrIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    }
    [self.accountTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:arrIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.accountTable endUpdates];
    // The line to reload the table might be not necessary as the animation updates the table
    // [self.accountTable reloadData];
  }
}
```

Comment: That still threw the assertion failure. We're using multiple datasources. The user touches a segment control and based on the index selected that datasource is used. I wonder if that might be part of the problem .

Comment: The problem is probably the cast to `NSMutableArray` in the `updateNonATITable` method. This has no effect. You have to initialize a `NSMutableArray` instance: `arrNonATIResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:dictRow1, dictRow2, nil];`

Comment: I had already changed that prior to using your code. I thought it was wrong to cast a mutable array and just fixed it throughout the code to be mutable.